# Can I use systemd's StateDirectory to point to an external hard drive?

Tags: systemd, bitcoin

I noticed that I am unable to change the StateDirectory of a [blockchain](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/999f8b24cca3ea3f2e19773adda4554b7e40de0c/contrib/init/bitcoind.service#L55) to an external hard drive because I believe that systemd only allows relative paths for the StateDirectory option. The reason I want to use an external hard drive is that my service's state is notoriously large. Specifically, I want to use it to store the bitcoin blockchain.

Should I simply forget about using a StateDirectory, or is there some other option? Or, do I have an incorrect concept of how to use StateDirectory entirely?

Comment: You can mount the filesystem on your external drive to the `StateDirectory` of the service with an fstab entry / mount unit. You might need / want to add the absolute path of the StateDirectory to `RequiresMountsFor` under `[Unit]` of the service.

Comment: With that said, I have no idea whether `StateDirectory` is really what you need to set to achieve what you want. (I mean, I do not know what it does or what you want to do exactly.)